# Checks after upgrading Magento to 1.9.3.6 (including SUPEE-10266)?

Tags: magento1.9.3, supee-10266

Which checks would you suggest to carry out in order to be sure that the Magento upgrade (including the patch SUPEE-10266) has been succesfully?
I made an upgrade and everything look good at first sight.
Thanks for your collaborations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control if into

```
app/etc/
```

exist file

```
applied.patches.list
```

and see into it patch log

**Another mode** is check your site on magereport.com